# Json policy for allowing SetInstanceProtection

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've used the following inline json policy to allow distinct IAM users to call SetDesiredCapacity:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:${region}:${userid}:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/*-${username}-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Each user has one autoscaling group of machines assigned to them with a name like ${companyname}-${username}-${machinetype}. After filling in the correct userid, username and region, the above inline json policy appears to work and users can call SetDesiredCapacity.

I'd like to allow users to set instance protection state on some of the instances in this autoscaling group also. For that, I tried creating this rule:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:SetInstanceProtection",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:${region}:${userid}:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/*-${username}-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, after adding this inline json policy to the IAM user's permissions, he still gets a "An error occurred while changing the termination protection setting of this instance". What do I need to change to this inline json policy so the user can modify instance protection state on autoscaling group instances?

Comment: Hi Ronald – did you have any luck building a policy that allows autoscaling:SetInstanceProtection to be run? I'm running into something similar here...